# Is there any way I can gift some reputation points to another user?

Tags: support, reputation, chat, new-users

I want to talk in a chatroom with some user to discuss a topic. But that user has less than 20 reputation. Is there any way I can gift him 20 of my reputation points?

Comment: Wouldn't it be a better question to ask whether there is a way to chat with people without enough rep?

Comment: IS there a way ? I assumed there is not.

Answer (score 3):

No. While bounties technically allow transferral of reputation from one account to another, they are not meant to be used as gifts, and any bounty that is found to be used that way will be refunded.

The user will have to earn the necessary reputation points on their own. It's not that hard - 20 points are just 2 upvotes.

Comment: The user is a newbie both to this site and to physics as well. So, very unlikely he will be able to contribute anything worth 2 upvotes, unless i deliberately upvote something he asks or answers even if they do not deserve an upvote. But i guess that is frowned upon as much as using bounties as gifts. So, yeah, i will try to figure something out.

Comment: Out of curiosity what happens if they talk in the comment section and the comment section is shifted a chatroom? Does the newbie still not get access to it?

Comment: @silverrahul *The user is a newbie both to this site and to physics as well. So, very unlikely he will be able to contribute anything worth 2 upvotes.* They could still ask a good question that gets up votes.

Comment: @MoreAnonymous They don't get access, that's why the prompt to move to chat does not appear in these cases, see [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/318314/263383).

Comment: I understand that people need to gain reputation to talk in chatrooms. But the kind of people who need to be moved from comment section to chatrooms for big to and fro discussions are precisely the kind of people who are completely newbies and do not have 20 reputations. It is sort of a catch 22

Comment: @silverrahul Chat reputation is not based on reputation on *this* site, but the sum of your reputation network-wide. Even someone with no experience in physics can earn the right to chat by earning 20 reputation on *another* site, or even a combination of several other sites. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/312081/380389.

Comment: @BioPhysicist " _They could still ask a good question that gets up votes_ " Like i said, very unlikely for a physics newbie to come up with a question worth upvotes. Look at the recent questions asked in last couple of days. It is the rare question that gets upvotes . And the only question that get upvotes are the kinds of questions that deal with some high level physics that are asked and answered by advanced level students that wont be understood by newbies. The kind of simple, curious questions that would come into the minds of newbies have generally all been asked

Comment: @silverrahul I'm not sure why you think that. I think you're assuming people new to physics can only ask off-topic homework questions. There are plenty of introductory questions that can still be good here. If you want to be helpful, maybe start by finding out how introductory questions here can still be good. Your pessimistic comments certainly wouldn't help a newcomer to physics if they were to read them. Everyone has to start somewhere.

Comment: " _There are plenty of introductory questions that can still be good here._ " I dont think so. Pick one question asked in last few days, that is introductory level and yet had upvotes. You wont find many. I know everyone has to start somewhere. But , the chat reputation requirement makes it so that newbie users can start somewhere, but that somewhere would not be in chatrooms

Comment: @silverrahul You raise a fair point. It's reasonable that established users could invite brand-new users to chat if the situation warrants it, without opening the doors to systematic abuse (say, by spammers). This has been requested on MSE [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277652/suggested-privilege-inviting-new-users-to-chat) and in linked threads. The SE devs have not said an explicit no, so this could still be on the cards, but I wouldn't hold my breath for it.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Yes. Newbies are precisely the kind of users who need to have long to and fro discussions because, their questions generally need to be modified a lot. IT is so true. _this would allow for a softer welcome to users that might otherwise be scared away by the abrupt nature of comments and close votes._